# Do Neuronal networks getting slow in adaption after a lot of training?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am a beginner in the neuronal network field and I want to understand a certain statement. A friend said that a neuronal network gets slower after you fit a lot of data in.

Right now, I just did the coursera ML course from androw ng. There, I implemented backpropagation. I thought it just adaptes the model related to the expected output by using different types of calculations. Nevertheless, it was not like the history was used to adapt the model. Just the current state of the neurons were checked and their weight were adapted backwards in combination with regularisation.

Is my assumption correct or am I wrong? Are there some libraries that use history data that could result in a slowly adapting model after a certain amount of training?

I want to use a simple neuronal network for reinforcement learning and I want to get an idea if I need to reset my model if the target environment changes for some reason. Otherwise my model would be slower and slower in adaption after time.

Thanks for any links and explanations in advanced!

Comment: Are you talking about the speed of loss drop? Please revise your question and try to stick to the terminology used in the community. That will make your question(s) more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have said, neural networks adapt by modifying their weights during the backpropagation step. Modifying these weights will not be slower as the training goes on since the number of steps to modify these weights will always remain the same. The amount of steps needed to run an example through your model will also remain the same, therefore not slowing down your network according to the amount of examples you fed it during training.

However, you can decide to change your learning rate during your training (generally decreasing it as epochs go on). According to the way the learning rate of your model evolves, the weights will be modified in a different manner, generally resulting in a smaller difference each epoch.